# Accessing Cassandra nodes in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have two Cassandra nodes and I'm developing a Java-Spark application.

I have one Spark Master and two slaves. The following code is used to connect to single Cassandra node:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "server");
```

How can I add additional Cassandra nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md) is quite clear:

```
new SparkConf(true)
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.123.10")
```

And just below:

"*Multiple hosts can be passed in using a comma separated list ("127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2"). These are the initial contact points only, all nodes in the local DC will be used upon connecting.*"

In other words, you just need to connect to the Spark master, which knows about the other machines in the cluster through the resource manager. The comma-separated list is useful when you want to connect to multiple clusters.

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing this if you are using scala. I could not find anything wrt Python though.

```
val connectorToClusterOne = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1"))
val connectorToClusterTwo = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.2"))


implicit val c = connectorToClusterOne
sc.cassandraTable("ks","tab")

implicit val c = connectorToClusterTwo
rddFromClusterOne.saveToCassandra("ks","tab")
```

Good Luck!!